# Android Button/TextView styling

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button

I want to have a [button like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JOi3.png).
It's basically a Text: *NEXT* with a *Chevron* on the right side.

I already tried a button with transparent background and `android:drawableRight`, but the padding of the drawable was looking weird.

How can I achieve the wanted look?

What I have so far:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/chevron_right"
            android:background="#00000000"/>
```

/*Sorry for posting a link and not the photo directly, but my reputations aren't high enough.*/

Comment: Share the code you have so far

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `FrameLayout`/`RelativeLayout` containing the `ImageButton` and an horizontal `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout` which contains the text and the chevron image aligned to the right. Something like this:

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_btn_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imbtn_btn_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/white_drawable" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_btn_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/next" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_btn_text"
                android:src="@drawable/chevron" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

This example is from my app, probably you'll need to adapt it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that it is possible to do it like this, but I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:drawablePadding="8dp"` to set the padding between the text and the drawable.[image]

Comment: Yea that works, but if it's set to 0dp the padding is still relatively much. Thats what I meant with "padding of the drawable was looking weird".

Comment: It is also possible to add a negative padding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the spaces between the views of chevron and borders with negative values of dp .
I had a similar problem last year and a proper combination of positive and negative dp fixed it

Comment: Nice idea, works partly, because the whole button size remains the same.

Comment: Oops missed that part . Ohkie so which part we are missing now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but that's how I will do the button you attached

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"     
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="NEXT"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```